# "User Name or Password does not match" even when the username and pass exist in database and are valid

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have been trying to create a sign up and login page and using only username and password worked but when I added the field of subject I can't log into the account I create and it says "User Name or Password does not match". I am pretty sure the error is in my LoginDataBaseAdapter but im not sure what is the error.

DataBaseHelper.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version)
    {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }
    // Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
// to create a new one.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db)
    {
        _db.execSQL(LoginDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);

    }
    // Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
// of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion)
    {
// Log the version upgrade.
        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

// Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple
// previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
// values.
// The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
// Create a new one.
        onCreate(_db);
    }

}
```

LoginDataBaseAdapter.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter
{
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
// SQL Statement to create a new database.
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
            "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME text,PASSWORD text,SUBJECT text); ";
    // Variable to hold the database instance
    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    // Context of the application using the database.
    private final Context context;
    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context)
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close()
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return db;
    }

    public void insertEntry(String userName,String password,String Subject)
    {
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
// Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
        newValues.put("SUBJECT", Subject);

// Insert the row into your table
        db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
    {
//String id=String.valueOf(ID);
        String where="USERNAME=?";
        int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
// Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
    }
    public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        String Subject= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SUBJECT"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;
    }
    public void updateEntry(String userName,String password,String Subject)
    {
// Define the updated row content.
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
// Assign values for each row.
        updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
        updatedValues.put("SUBJECT", Subject);
        String where="USERNAME = ?";
        db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java+login page

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// create a instance of SQLite Database
        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

// Get The Reference Of Buttons
        btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIN);
        btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);

// Set OnClick Listener on SignUp button
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

/// Create Intent for SignUpActivity abd Start The Activity
                Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUPActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSignUP);
            }
        });
    }
    // Methos to handleClick Event of Sign In Button
    public void signIn(View V)
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
        dialog.setTitle("Login");

// get the References of views
        final EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
        final EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

        Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

// Set On ClickListener
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
// get The User name and Password
                String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();

// fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

// check if the Stored password matches with Password entered by user
                if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("USERNAME",userName);
                    editor.apply();
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), signedin.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("USERNAME",userName);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
// Close The Database
        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

SignUPActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUPActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword,editTextSubject;
    Button btnCreateAccount;

    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

// get Instance of Database Adapter
        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

// Get References of Views
        editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
        editTextSubject=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);

        btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);
        btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
                String Subject=editTextSubject.getText().toString();

// check if any of the fields are vaccant
                if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals("")||Subject.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
// check if both password matches
                if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
// Save the Data in Database
                    loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password, Subject);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

Contact.java

```
public class Contact {
    String uname;
    String pass;
    String subject;
    public Contact(String uname,String pass,String subject)
    {
        this.uname=uname;
        this.pass=pass;
        this.subject=subject;
    }
    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do - to browse you sqlite database data. There are different tools that can help you in that ([DB Browser](https://medium.com/@mattyskala/browse-sqlite-database-in-android-studio-4fbba6cca105) for example). Without that you can only guess what is the source of your problem.

There are several possible scenarios you can get analysing your problem test-case:

1. There are no rows in your table with the username you test. Since your save-login code has no mistakes (it seemed so), this is probably not the case.
2. There is only one row with the username and saved password differs. If it's so, you're searching for the black cat in black room :-)
3. There is only one row with the username and saved password the same as you're trying to test. According to your code I think it can't be.
4. There are several rows with the same username. Technically it can be because you haven't put some check to prevent keeping one username with different passwords. By the way, you have method "updateEntry", but you don't use it anywhere, just "insertEntry". May be it's time to use it?

   My sixth sense tell me that variant 4 will be the winner

Comment: after using the sqlite browser it seems as thought my Subject field isnt added to the database for some reason, idk if thats the reason but it might have some affect.
@sergiy tikhonov

Comment: If you change table's structure you need to increase database version (your static final int DATABASE_VERSION) and implement [onUpgrade method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)). In addition you can try [Room library](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), it's among must-have stack for android developer nowadays